# WPF Resource section not effecting my Label control in the view

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a style for a “required field” label which should place a red asterisk “*” in front of the label. Here is my xaml taken from the Application.Resources section of my WPF application:

```
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="RequiredField">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" FontSize="10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The xaml in my view uses the resource like this:

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource RequiredField}" Content="Name:"/>
```

Annoyingly it doesn’t appear to modify the label. Can anyone tell me what I’ve done wrong?

Comment: Debugging XAML can be quite a pain :)
Try these 2 things:
1- Is there any anohter resource down in the chain (starting from Application.Resources) called RequiredField that can be overriding this resource?
2- Try to eliminate setters and see if it affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your style seems to be wrong. I would try it that way.

```xml
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="RequiredField">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" FontSize="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

This should do the trick, but it's totally untested.

Comment: This small change fixed my problem. Saved me some time. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The template is assigned to the Content property. That is wrong.

Instead it can be assigned to the Template property but in this case it might be better to use the Validation.ErrorTemplate property because it is meant for validation adorners.

[From this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/06/24/wpf-textbox-validation.aspx):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="16" Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                    Source="Assets/warning_48.png"/>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="Holder"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding ElementName=Holder, 
               Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<TextBox x:Name="Box" 
     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}">
```